# Semaphore when using a pre-emptive kernel

Tags: operating-system, kernel, embedded

I know what a binary semaphore is: it is a flag when is set to 1 by an ISR of an interrupt.

But what is a semaphore when we are using a pre-emptive kernel, say FreeRTOS? Is it the same as binary semaphore?

Comment: It's a bit more than a flag, or count.  A semaphore also has some container, usually a queue, for threads waiting on it.

Comment: A binary semaphore is just one application of an RTOS semaphore.  The FreeRTOS website has [a good write up](http://www.freertos.org/Inter-Task-Communication.html)

Comment: I researched it about a bit and I am under the impression that it acts like a counter of some sort that how many resources are used uptil now by counting the flags in the ISR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it is a flag when is set to 1 by an ISR of an interrupt.

That is neither a complete nor accurate description of a semaphore.  What you have described is merely a *flag*.  A semaphore is a synchronisation object; there are three forms provided by a typical RTOS:

- Binary Semaphore
- Counting Sempahore
- Mutual Exclusion Semaphore (Mutex)

In the case of a binary semaphore, there are two operations *give* and *take*.  A task taking a semaphore will *block* (i.e. suspend execution and allow other lower or equal priority threads to run threads to run) until some other thread or interrupt handler gives the semaphore.  Binary semaphores are used to signal between threads and from ISRs to threads.  They are often used to implement *deferred interrupt handlers*, so that an ISR can ve bery short, and the handler benefit from RTOS mechanisms that are not allowed in an ISR (anything that blocks or suspends execution).

Multiple threads may block on a single semaphore, but only one of those tasks will respond take the semaphore.  Some RTOS have a *flush* operation (VxWorks for example) that puts all threads waiting on a semaphore in the *ready* state simultaneously - in which case they will run according to the priority scheduling scheme.

A *Counting Semaphore* is similar to a *Binary Semaphore*, except that it can be given multiple times, and tasks may take the semaphore without blocking until the count is zero.

A *Mutex* is used for resource locking. It is possible to use a binary semaphore for this, but a mutex provides features that make this safer.  The operations on a mutex are *lock* and *unlock*.  When a thread locks a mutex, and another task attempts to lock the same mutex, the second (and any subsequent) task blocks until the first task unlocks it.  This can be used to prevent more than one thread accessing a resource (memory or I/O) simultaneously.  A thread may lock a mutex multiple times; a count is maintained, so that it must be unlocked an equal number of times before the lock is released.  This allows a thread to nest locks.

A special feature of a mutex is that if a thread with the lock is a lower priority that a task requesting the lock, then the lower priority task is boosted to the priority of the higher in order to prevent a priority inversion where a middle priority task may preempt the low priority task with the lock increasing the length of time the higher priority task must wait this rendering the scheduling non-deterministic.

The above descriptions are *typical*; specific RTOS implementations may differ.  For example FreeRTOS distinguishes between a *mutex* and a *recursive mutex*, the latter supporting the nestability feature; while the first is marginally more efficient where nesting is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer , btw I was taking about binary semaphore in bare metal , I usually used it to keep the ISR short

Comment: @johnny : If you only have a main context and an ISR context,  there is not concept of "blocking", the main thread simply spins waiting on a flag or polls it and continues - either way, that is not a semaphore.

Comment: @Clifford well, semaphores are often used for comms between an ISR and user-state threads. send, (but certainly not wait) on a semaphore is safe on all OS I have used.  If the ISR exits via the scheduler, (instead of the usual direct interrupt-return), such an ISR can make a thread that was waiting on the semaphore ready/running 'immediately'.

Comment: @MartinJames :  I have not said anything different (in fact I have said *exactly* that in my answer).  My comment refers to Johnny's simplistic understanding of what a semaphore is and his use of a simple flag variable in a system without an RTOS.

Comment: @johnny :  I am aware that your question was specifically about *binary semaphore*, the explanation of other forms of semaphore were to provide context to the answer.

Comment: Actually my question was about the difference in semaphores when we are using baremetal and when using a preemtive kernel but your answer was very detailed and helped me alot :) thanks

Comment: @johnny : Yes and my point is that a semaphore is specifically a multithreading mechanism, without multiple threads, there is no need for semaphores, and what you were describing is not a semaphore.

Answer (score 2):

Semaphores are not just flags, or counts. They support send and wait operations. A user-space thread can wait on a semaphore without unnecessary and unwanted polling and be made ready/running 'immediately' when another thread, or an appropriately-designed driver/ISR, sends a unit.

By 'appropriately-designed driver/ISR', I mean one that can perform a send() operation and then exit via the OS scheduler whenever it needs to set a waiting thread ready/running.

Such a mechanism is vitally important on preemptive kernels because it allows them to achieve very good I/O performance without wasting time, CPU cycles and memory-bandwidth on polling.  Non-preemptive systems are hopelessly slow, latency-ridden and wasteful at I/O and this is why they are essentially no longer used and why we put up with all the synchro/locking/queueing etc issues.